# nginx: Can't bind to port (already in use) although no tasks running on that port

Tags: linux-mint, nginx, port

i just chose nginx for my webserver and I did follow this tutorial: https://github.com/groovemonkey/hands_on_linux-self_hosted_wordpress_for_linux_beginners

However, I just can't connect to my webserver.

When i do `$ sudo nginx` I get the following response:

```
nginx: [warn] duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:34
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

`$ sudo netstat -plten | grep 80`gives the following result:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          70851       9943/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          70850       9943/nginx -g daemo
```

This is my nginx.conf:

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  auto;

pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    error_log  /var/log/nginx_error.log error;
    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # SSL
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # no sslv3 (poodle etc.)
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Gzip Settings
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript text/xml text/css application/font-sfnt;

    fastcgi_cache_path /usr/share/nginx/cache/fcgi levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m max_size=1024m inactive=1h;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This is my site.conf (located in /etc/nginx/conf.d/):

```
server {

    listen [::]:80;

    server_name  _;

    client_max_body_size 20m;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root   /home/tutorialinux/public_html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
            # Basic
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_index index.php;

            # Create a no cache flag
            set $no_cache "";

            # Don't ever cache POSTs
            if ($request_method = POST) {
              set $no_cache 1;
            }

            # Admin stuff should not be cached
            if ($request_uri ~* "/(wp-admin/|wp-login.php)") {
              set $no_cache 1;
            }

            # WooCommerce stuff should not be cached
            if ($request_uri ~* "/store.*|/cart.*|/my-account.*|/checkout.*|/addons.*") {
              set $no_cache 1;
            }

            # If we are the admin, make sure nothing
            # gets cached, so no weird stuff will happen
            if ($http_cookie ~* "wordpress_logged_in_") {
              set $no_cache 1;
            }

            # Cache and cache bypass handling
            fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
            fastcgi_cache microcache;
            fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$server_name$request_uri$args;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 404 10m;
            fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating;


            # General FastCGI handling
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/tutorialinux.sock;
            fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
            fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
            fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include fastcgi_params;         
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff|ttf|svg|otf)$ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            access_log off;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  snapecraft.ddns.net;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.snapecraft.ddns.net/$1 permanent;
}
```

System is Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia.

## EDIT 1:

Now nginx is able to bind the port (forgot to replace default.conf), but I still get Connection Refused. Has this to do with PHP / FastCGI?

Comment: Do you have SELinux or AppArmor enabled?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what this is :(

Comment: Restart the service

Comment: I already did this several times

Answer (score 1):

Just try kill or terminate existing nginx process. And start it again. Now you already have nginx process which is running in daemon mode. And this process is blocking 80 port.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm afraid but I already tried this several times. Now nginx is able to bind  the port, but I'm unable to connect (Connection refused)

Comment: Try to replace listen [::]:80; with listen :80; or with your ip address: listen 1.2.3.4:80;

Comment: Doesn't work either... :(

Comment: Still nothing in your access and error logs?